# How to center a semantic-ui-react form in the menu bar?

Tags: css, semantic-ui-react

I have a semantic-ui-react form `LocationSearchForm` in the menu bar like below:
[image]

I put `LocationSearchForm` inside the `<Menu.Item>`

```
<Menu.Item>
    <LocationSearchForm />
</Menu.Item>
```

But as you see, the form isn't getting vertically centered. Other `menu.item` like links, `signin` and `signout` are perfectly centered, only displaying this form has a bit problem. How can I get it vertically centered? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting space below `input`, because when you write,

```
<Form>
    <Form.Field>
      <input placeholder='Your City' />
    </Form.Field>
</Form>
```

Your `Form.Field` getting `margin-bottom : 1rem`.

You need to remove `margin`. Simple way is inline style,

```
<Form.Field style={{marginBottom:'0'}}>
```

Or you can assign a class-name, and then write `CSS` for that class-name.

Comment: I inspected the form by checking the styles, and see the marginBottom is already been set to 0. Actually the form is centered in the navbar, but the problem is that the height of the form is a bit high. Question is how can I change the height of the form? Thank you!!!

Comment: I set the height by doing this `<Form style={{height: "40px"}}>`. Thank you!